# C# linq - Order by alphabetical, then by certain value

Tags: c#, linq

I am stuck on an issue here. I have a column called Title and the titles look like this

AAA Interior, BBB Interior, CCC Interior, AAA End, BBB End, CCC End.

What I am trying to do is get the Title column in alphabetical and have them in order or Interior then End so my data looks like this:

AAA Interior, AAA End, BBB Interior, BBB End, CCC Interior, CCC End.

This is what I tried:

```
var results = qry.GroupBy(x => x.Title).Select(x => new { x.FirstOrDefault().Type, x.FirstOrDefault().Title, x.FirstOrDefault().Plan, x.FirstOrDefault().Id, x.FirstOrDefault().Image }).ToList();

                        results = results.OrderBy(x => x.Title).OrderByDescending(x => x.Plan.FirstOrDefault().Title == "Interior").ToList();
```

But it gives me this result:

AAA Interior, BBB Interior, CCC Interior, AAA End, BBB End, CCC End.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0)

Comment: That did not work, the results came by AAA End, AAA Interior, BBB End, BBB Interior, CCC End, CCC Interior

Comment: Ah, my bad, it's `ThenByDescending`. You get the idea :).

Comment: I get the same result: AAA End, AAA Interior, BBB End, BBB Interior, CCC End, CCC

Comment: If you want to sort Plan Title in an arbitrary order try:
 ` var planOrder = new List<string>{"Interior", "End"}; 
 var sorted = qry.OrderBy(b => b.Title).ThenBy(b => planOrder.IndexOf(b.Plan.Title));`

Comment: @PhillipNgan I tried that and it didn't work